# google+ api - random string added at the end of redirect url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used google+ api for authentication and retrieving user-data using CodeIgniter framework.

After authentication, a random string is added at the end of the redirect uri I have specified in the code.

This leads to a blank view. How do I fix that?

PS : The same code works absolutely fine on localhost!

> controller - user_authentication.php

```
<?php
// Start session

session_start();

class User_Authentication extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {

// Include two files from google-php-client library in controller
include_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/vendor/autoload.php";
include_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php";
include_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/vendor/google/auth/src/OAuth2.php";

// Store values in variables from project created in Google Developer Console
$client_id = 'CLIENT ID';
$client_secret = 'SECRET';
$redirect_uri = 'http://mgdevx.byethost14.com/blackjack/index.php/user_authentication/index/';
$simple_api_key = 'KEY';

// Create Client Request to access Google API
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("PHP Google OAuth Login Example");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setDeveloperKey($simple_api_key);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");

// Send Client Request
$objOAuthService = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

// Add Access Token to Session
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

// Set Access Token to make Request
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

// Get User Data from Google and store them in $data
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
$userData = $objOAuthService->userinfo->get();
$data['userData'] = $userData;
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
$data['authUrl'] = $authUrl;
}
// Load view and send values stored in $data
$this->load->view('google_authentication', $data);
}

// Unset session and logout
public function logout() {
unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
redirect(base_url());
}
}
?>
```

> view - google_authentication.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 0px)" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/styleresponsive1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 0px)" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/styleresponsive2.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="envelope">
<?php if (isset($authUrl)){ ?>
<header id="sign_in">
<h2>CodeIgniter Login With Google Oauth PHP</h2>
</header>
<hr>
<div id="content">
<center><a href="<?php echo $authUrl; ?>"><img id="google_signin" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/google_login.jpg" width="100%" ></a></center>
</div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<!-- <header id="info">
<a target="_blank" class="user_name" href="<?php echo $userData->link; ?>" /><img class="user_img" src="<?php echo $userData->picture; ?>" width="15%" />
<?php echo '<p class="welcome"><i>Welcome ! </i>' . $userData->name . "</p>"; ?></a><a class='logout' href='https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user_authentication/logout'>Logout</a>
</header> -->

<h3>Fill in some extra details</h3>
<?php           
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('email' => $userData->email));
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('gender' => $userData->gender));
        redirect('main/gregister');
?>
<?php }?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> controller - main.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('main-page');
    }

    public function gregister()
    {
        $gmail = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $this->load->model('model_register');
        $value = $this->model_register->checkmail($gmail);
        if($value == 1)
        {
            $this->load->view('gregister');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('success-page');
        }   
    }     
}
```

For one account, the redirect uri is: http://mgdevx.byethost14.com/blackjack/index.php/user_authentication/index/**?code=4/mjmogtOZrJxwHvR40vXdCEZ8tBgV-KWSUe8Nav6j-WA#**

The bold part is added extra, leading to a blank view.
EDIT:

> error_log.txt

```
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 01:45:42 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/favicon.ico<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:27 -0500 AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/mgdevx.byethost14.com<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:27 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:27 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:27 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:27 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:39 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:39 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:39 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:39 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:49 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:49 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:49 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:45:49 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:46:01 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:46:01 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:46:01 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 02:46:01 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 05:45:32 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 05:45:32 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 05:45:32 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 05:45:32 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:45:42 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:45:42 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:45:42 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:45:42 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:45:52 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:45:52 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:45:52 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:45:52 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 08:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/favicon.ico<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 08:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 08:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 08:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 08:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:26 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:26 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:26 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:26 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/favicon.ico<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:37 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:48 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:48 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:48 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:48 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:48 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/favicon.ico<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:59 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:59 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:59 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 09:45:59 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 10:45:52 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/favicon.ico<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 12:46:04 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/favicon.ico<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:46:03 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:46:03 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:46:03 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:46:03 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:46:03 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/favicon.ico<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:46:14 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/style.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:46:14 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive2.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:46:14 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/css/styleresponsive1.css<br>
Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:46:14 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol8_4/byethost14.com/b14_17744405/htdocs/blackjack/images/google_login.jpg<br>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am asking that due to the extra part added, desired view isn't loaded. How do I fix that? Moreover, the same code works perfectly on localhost.

Comment: At the end of view file you have `redirect()` function.

Comment: Try looking your host's error log to figure out. The redirect returns error 500 on my browser. You may adit and add what the error_log shows when you do the login.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas error_log.txt added. I think they are all css errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'normal' PHP urls, but CI have their own URL format `siteURL.com/controller/function/param1/param2` (by default, you could change this in config.php 
`$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`). Check more in: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

If you change the url for: http://mgdevx.byethost14.com/blackjack/index.php/user_authentication/index/4/mjmogtOZrJxwHvR40vXdCEZ8tBgV-KWSUe8Nav6j-WA#

(without the `?code=`) part it redirects to the desired page (I guess, almost is not blank).

Then you should catch the param and assign to $code var. Hope it helps!

UPDATE

You should change:

```
public function index() {
```

to:

```
public function index($code == NULL) { //$code will 'catch' the param
```

and then in: `

```
// Add Access Token to Session
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {`
```

changed to:

```
// Add Access Token to Session
if ($code != NULL) {
$client->authenticate($code);
```

Then, the url: http://mgdevx.byethost14.com/blackjack/index.php/user_authentication/index/4/mjmogtOZrJxwHvR40vXdCEZ8tBgV-KWSUe8Nav6j-WA#

will call the controller `user_authentication` function index() and $code = 4, if you wish to get the `mjmog....-WA#` part, you have to add another param in the index() function like: `index($code==NULL,$api_key==NULL)`

UPDATE 2:

Ok. We are are at the beggining I guess. I think you have a URL problem. I do the registration and the redirections return with a '500 Server Error' that usually is a URL missconfiguration.

¿Did you set in config.php the enable_query_strings?:
`$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;

Did you have a .htaccess file? Could you post it?

Comment: Can you please write a sample of it , as I am doing api work for the first time. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Plus, when we load the view according to your method, the data which was being passed to the view is lost.

Comment: If you have charts like "/" in your response code, CI will interpret that is another param... You will have to parse it before (in route.php).

Comment: There aren't any '/' in the response.

Comment: I see he one in your redirect uri: http://mgdevx.byethost14.com/blackjack/index.php/user_authentication/index/?code=4/mjmogtOZrJxwHvR40vXdCEZ8tBgV-KWSUe8Nav6j-WA# after the "4"

Comment: As your problem was: "This leads to a blank view. How do I fix that?" and this now is solved, I suggest you to mark this question as solved and reopen new one with your new problem (something like "CI Google Service Oauth2 problem with passing data to the view" or "CI google+ api problem with redirect uri") in order to the question was more close to your problem and obtain better answers.

Comment: Actually, what I mean to say is that after I implemented the solution, the authentication itself has stopped(Gmail doesn't ask you to login) and the view remains blank. Though, the url is now correct.

Comment: If I go to the page: http://mgdevx.byethost14.com/blackjack/index.php/user_authentication/index/4mjmogtOZrJxwHvR40vXdCEZ8tBgV-KWSUe8Nav6j-WA  I see a page with the title "CodeIgniter Login With Google Oauth PHP". If I click to the image (that is broken) the page redirects me to the Gmail auth service. I didn't click for authorization but all seems right.

Comment: Currently, I have restored the code to defaut settings.Situation in  my previous comment takes place if I apply your solution.

Comment: Did you autoload the 'url' helper class? From here: http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-google-oauth-php/ (I think is the same example of yours), there is some users that have your same problem (blank page) and the solution is: `include the ‘url’ in helper of your autoload.php`